# axios catch doesn't catch error

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I'm using `axios 0.17.0` with the following code:

```
this.props.userSignupRequest(this.state)
  .then( res => { console.log(res.data) } )
  .catch( err => { this.setState({ errors: err.response }) } )
```

And the server is set to return a `400` when user signup validation doesn't pass. That also shows up in console: `POST 400 (Bad Request)`, but the `setState` is not being executed. Why is that? I also tried `console.log(err)` and nothing.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `userSignupRequest`?

Comment: And what makes you think the `setState()` isn't being executed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few issues could be at play, we'll likely need to see more of your code to know for sure.

Axios 0.17.0 will throw an error on the 400 response status. The demo below shows this.

The unexpected behavior could be due to the asynchronous behavior of `setState()`. If you're trying to `console.log` the state immediately after calling `setState()` that won't work. You'll need to use the `setState` callback.

```js
const signinRequest = () => {
  return axios.post('https://httpbin.org/status/400');
}   
  
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      errors: null
    }
  }
  
  handleSignin = () => {
    this.props.userSigninRequest()
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result.status);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          errors: error.response.status
        }, () => {
          console.error(this.state.errors);
        });
      });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <button onClick={this.handleSignin}>Signin</button>
        {this.state.errors}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App userSigninRequest={signinRequest} />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.17.0/axios.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 11):

In my case (axios 0.27.2), 400 responses are indeed handled as errors by axios.

This problem could happen due to a badly written response interceptor which doesn't return Promise.reject in unhandled cases.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response,
    (error) => {
      if (condition) {
        // Handle error
      } else {
        // This is important, so that unhandled cases make axios throw errors
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: Yep, that "Promise.reject" line is very important - the cause of 2 hours of head scratching wondering why Axios wasn't raising any exceptions on errors when used with React Query! Thanks for the post.

Comment: @MrChris same...

Answer (score 6):

`POST 400 (Bad Request)` is not an error, it is a not successful response. `catch` fires when there is an error on request.

If you want to catch `400` or similar HTTP errors you need to check [`status`](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema)

**Example**

```
this.props.userSignupRequest(this.state)
  .then( res => { console.log(res.status) } )
  .catch( err => { this.setState({ errors: err.response }) } )
```

Comment: This is incorrect, 400 is an error. I don't know if it's still relevant to the year, but it should be.

Comment: I upvoted by mistake and now I can't remove my vote... Actually in my case (axios 0.27.2) 400 responses are indeed handled as errors by axios. My mistake was a poorly written interceptor, I will add a different answer to address this issue.