# react axios then works but catch doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I've read the following questions but I couldn't find the solution.

- https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960
- https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/41
- [axios catch doesn't catch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146121/axios-catch-doesnt-catch-error)

I wanna to get errors 400, 500, ... someone has said you should catch in then but I tried it and nothing happened. for test I wrote a function to get error 404, 400, ...

```
export const myAxios = url => {
  Axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      // Success
      console.log("then response ", response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // Error
      if (error.response) {
        console.log("error respone", error.response);
        // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
        // that falls out of the range of 2xx
        // console.log(error.response.data);
        // console.log(error.response.status);
        // console.log(error.response.headers);
      } else if (error.request) {
        // The request was made but no response was received
        // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the
        // browser and an instance of
        // http.ClientRequest in node.js
        console.log("erros request: ", error.request);
      } else {
        // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
        console.log("Error message", error.message);
      }
      console.log("errors config : ", error.config);
    });
};
```

axios doesn't catch errors and browser console logs this:

```
xhr.js:172 GET http://localhost:3000/app/..../choices 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:172
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:11
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:59
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:53
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:68
wrap @ bind.js:9
myAxios @ textaxios.js:4
(anonymous) @ List.jsx:14
commitHookEffectList @ react-dom.development.js:22030
```

Any tips or help will be appreciated.

packages:

```
   "axios": "^0.19.0"
   "react": "^16.12.0"
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not logging this `console.log(error.request);` ? you have no way of knowing, try adding some text to the other error logs you have to rule that out.

Comment: Done but it's not logging, is it related to local? I'm working on my project in local host now.

Comment: reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798451/how-to-catch-and-handle-error-response-422-with-redux-axios, it could be that axios is parsing the error into a response. Can you try `console.log("error", error)` in the catch? Another thing that may be worth trying is using an interceptor, similar to the one mentioned by  VSG24  in https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960

Comment: In addition to the above, what version of axios are you using? There was a change a couple years ago to add `validateStatus` config option so without that change it may be sending you to your `.then` callback on 4XX responses.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine. Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-hopper-jt96x) that replicates it. You should be seeing the error in console. The only strange thing that I see is that `Axios` with capitalized A. How is `Axios` defined exactly?

Comment: Actually as other friend said it should works fine, but in my localhost it just works when response is 200, and no error catches when it has error

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, perhaps it's the local endpoint (resource) that you're trying to get to?

Here's an example using an example placeholder service:

```js
document.getElementById('btn-valid').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Valid URL
  myAxios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
})

document.getElementById('btn-invalid').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Invalid URL
  myAxios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todus/1')
})

const myAxios = url => {
  axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('success', response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error)
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>


<button id="btn-invalid">Invalid URL</button>
<button id="btn-valid">Valid URL</button>
```

Additionally, you can try using Axios [interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) to 'intercept' requests or responses before they're handled by `then` or `catch`:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
        // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
        // Do something with response data
        console.log('inside interceptor success')
        return response;
      }, error => {
        // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
        // Do something with response error
        console.log('inside interceptor error')
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
```